# LoadError: cannot load such file -- google/api_client

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

I have installed the google-api-client gem, but when i try to require it i get this error

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- google/api_client
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

The gem is there when i checked my gem list. 
I'm using ruby alone not rails.

I don't see what is happening, is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Check [this.](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/132#issuecomment-248841641)

Comment: Which version of this gem and how are you running this ruby applicaiton?

Comment: Try to add `require 'google-api-client'` in start of file

Comment: @DiodonHystrix the google/apis trick worked. But i still don't know it couldn't find the gem... I do not think it's a version problem since i just installed it for the first time. Thank you by the way !

Comment: Well it looks like the newest version does not have `api_client` directory, instead it has `api` one.

Comment: Well it seems like the sample example provided by youtube team (for ruby) are completely wrong. They require file that do not exist, call function with wrong number of argument and some that do not even exist. I'm talking about the upload a video one. Is this normal ? Should i stop trying to use the sdk and just use direct request ?